# Setting up Sudo in CentOS-7

Tags: centos, ssh, sudo

In CentOS 6.5, i would do the following to setup sudo for users -

1. useradd -G wheel -c "John Smith" jsmith
2. visudo
3. uncomment this line - %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
4. usermod -G wheel -a jsmith
5. restart sshd - /etc/init.d/sshd restart
6. ssh login as jsmith and type 'sudo bash'

When i try the same thing in CentOS 7, i see the following in /var/log/secure -

```
Oct  8 05:20:00 localhost sudo: jsmith : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/jsmith ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
```

Is this procedure not valid for CentOS-7 anymore?

More info -

file /etc/group has this -

```
wheel:x:10:randomperson,cartman,jsmith
```

visudo shows this -

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Allows members of the 'sys' group to run networking, software,
## service management apps and more.
# %sys ALL = NETWORKING, SOFTWARE, SERVICES, STORAGE, DELEGATING, PROCESSES, LOCATE, DRIVERS

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
wheel   ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

output of sudo -l command -

```
[jsmith@localhost ~]$ sudo -l
[sudo] password for jsmith:
Sorry, user jsmith may not run sudo on localhost.
[jsmith@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Syntax seems to be correct. 
Have you tried to add `jsmith ALL=(ALL) ALL` in visudo?

Comment: It works for me (with a new test user).  Check the `%wheel` line is definitely uncommented and check `/etc/group` to make sure that `jsmith` is in the `wheel` row. No need to restart `ssh`, just log out and back in again.

Comment: Just doublechecked.
/etc/group - wheel:x:10:randomperson,cartman,jsmith

visudo - 
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Allows members of the 'sys' group to run networking, software,
## service management apps and more.
# %sys ALL = NETWORKING, SOFTWARE, SERVICES, STORAGE, DELEGATING, PROCESSES, LOCATE, DRIVERS

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
wheel   ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a '%' in the example posted.

It's supposed to be

```
%wheel   ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

not

```
wheel   ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Comment: lol, yup works now. thanks. i will take my darwin award and leave.